# RaspberryPi bluetooth le application always asks for pairing on iOS

Tags: c#, dbus, bluez, raspberry-pi4, ios-bluetooth

Im currently working on a Mobile application which connects to a Ble peripheral and reads data from it. In order to test if the connection is working. I have written a small C# application that utilizes the RaspberryPi4 bluetooth via [DBus](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus) with BlueZ.

Everything works except that when connecting to iOS a pairing request is issued by the raspberry, eventhough I do not have any encrypted characteristics.

I have read on the [Apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678925) that this is because bluetoothd is automaticly trying to read the battery level of the phone. But sadly even after the fix suggested there I get the pairing requests.

Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi have `sudo btmon` running in a separate terminal to see more detailed debug information on what is causing the pairing request. You can also write the btmon information to a file and take it into `wireshark` to help process the information. e.g. `sudo btmon -w pairing_problem_ios.log`. I think the document you linked to is wrong. The file that should be edited to make a permanent change is:  `/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe disabling this bluez config option in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` would prevent the pi from trying to read characteristics from the iOS device, if that is the issue:

```
# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. For BR/EDR this option is really only needed for qualification since the
# BITE tester doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases, for LE
# this disables the GATT client functionally so it can be used in system which
# can only operate as peripheral.
# Defaults to 'true'.
#ReverseServiceDiscovery = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection min and max intervals, they shall be compliant with the iOS guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf (page 180 - 40.6 Connection Parameters).

You can tune them like this:

```
echo "30" > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
echo "45" > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
```

The default values worked for me: [24,40]